# Retrofit 2.0.0-beta4: Unable to create converter for class

Tags: android, retrofit, android-6.0-marshmallow, retrofit2, activeandroid

Here are my files:

### build.gradle:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.6.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.1'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.0.0-beta4'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.0.0-beta4'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.databinding:baseLibrary:2.0.0-beta2'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile 'com.michaelpardo:activeandroid:3.1.0-SNAPSHOT'
}
```

### Pojo Model class:

```
@Table(name = "ModelTableName")
public class DataEntity extends Model {

    @Column(name = "_id")
    private String _id;

    @Expose
    @Column(name = "imageUri")
    private String uri;

    @Expose
    @Column(name = "title")
    private String title;

    public DataEntity() {
        super();
    }

    public void set_id(String _id) {
        this._id = _id;
    }

    public void setUri(String uri) {
        this.uri = uri;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String get_id() {
        return _id;
    }

    public String getUri() {
        return uri;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }
}
```

## Retrofit service:

```
protected Retrofit build() {
        if (null == retrofit) {
            HttpLoggingInterceptor interceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
            interceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);
            OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder().addInterceptor(interceptor).build();

            retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                    .client(client)
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .build();
        }
        return retrofit;
    }
```

I am using retrofit for API calls and for database using ActiveAndroid.
On Pre 6.0 Android devices, an app is working perfectly. 
Not able to identify the root cause.

### Gone through the following post:

[Retrofit 2 beta-4. Android 6. Unable to create convertor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35228962/retrofit-2-beta-4-android-6-unable-to-create-convertor)

I couldn't understand that what is the need to use gson or gsonbuilder ?

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

They have now released a stable version of Retrofit.
Try using this

```
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.0.0'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.0.0'
```

Also if you are using ActiveAndroid then you should create your retrofit object like this

```
Retrofit retrofit = new new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
            .client(client)
            .addConverterFactory(
                    GsonConverterFactory.create(new GsonBuilder()
                            .serializeNulls()
                            .excludeFieldsWithModifiers(Modifier.FINAL, Modifier.TRANSIENT, Modifier.STATIC)
                            .create()))
            .build();
```

because Model class contains some static and transient fields.
Hope this helps.